# Sitecore security hardening Paas

Tags: security, paas

We have setup a Paas enviroment with Sitecore 9.0.1 XP scaled. 
The problem is that Sitecore login and admin tools are available on the Content Delivery server. My understanding is that Security hardening should be done by default on the Paas.

The role is defined as ContentDelivery in webconfig
The package used is Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (Cloud)_cd.scwdp.zip

Does anyone know where the Security hardening should take place?
Is it in the Arm templates or should it be done by PS scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer it myself since I found the problem.
We had edited the Web.config and accidently removed the location tag that controlled access to sitecore files